# Python3 - Convert unicode literals string to unicode string

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode, unicode-literals

From command line parameters (`sys.argv`) I receive string of unicode literals like this: `'\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442\u0021'`

For example this script uni.py:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[1])
```

**command line:**

```
python uni.py \u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442\u0021
```

**output:**

```
\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442\u0021
```

I want to convert it to unicode string `'Привет!'`

Comment: Please clarify what you want to do. `'\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442\u0021'` *is* the string `'Привет!'`.

Comment: To clarify the above: that representation is Python's representation *only*, because some terminals cannot print Unicode. Do this simple experiment: print out the ordinal value of the first character. You will see it is `1055` (`0x41f` in decimal), and not `92`, the value for a backslash (nor `39` – the single quote – because that is *also* not "part of the string", even though it gets printed by Python as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to convert it the Unicode, because it already **is** Unicode. In Python 3.x, strings are Unicode by default. You only have to convert them (to or from `bytes`) when you want to read or write bytes, for example, when writing to a file.

If you just print the string, you'll get the correct result, assuming your terminal supports the characters.

```py
print('\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442\u0021')
```

This will print:

> Привет!

**UPDATE**

After updating your question it became clear to me that the mentioned string is not really a string literal (or unicode literal), but input from the command line. In that case you could use the "unicode-escape" encoding to get the result you want.
Note that encoding works from Unicode to bytes, and decoding works from bytes to Unicode. In this case you want a transformation from Unicode to Unicode, so you have to add a "dummy" decoding step using latin-1 encoding, which transparently converts Unicode codepoints to bytes.

The following code will print the correct result for your example:

```py
text = sys.argv[1].encode('latin-1').decode('unicode-escape')
print(text)
```

**UPDATE 2**

Alternatively, you could use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse the string from the input. However, this method expects a proper Python literal, including the quotes. You could do something like to solve this:

```py
text = ast.literal_eval("'" + sys.argv[1] + "'")
```

But note that this would break if you would have a quote as part of your input string. I think it's a bit of a hack, since the method is probably not intended for the purpose you use it. The unicode-escape is simpler and robuster. However, what the best solution is depends on what you're building.